# imakeidx does not run makeindex when output-directory is set and named index does not work

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I'm trying to make a document with an index. I have two issues with that (probably both caused by the first. I use the package `imakeidx` since that *should* run makeindex automatically, but it does not. I set an `output-directory` which seems to be the culprit.

have this mwe:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
add something to the index \index{something}
add something else to the index \index{somethin else}
add item to the index \index{item}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

when I then run

```
pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex
pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex
```

This results in a document containing no index, just:

[image]

Now, when I run makeindex separately, like so:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape --output-directory=build main.tex
cd build
makeindex main.idx
cd ../
pdflatex --shell-escape --output-directory=build main.tex
```

I do get an index in the PDF. However, going this route things fail when I try to name the indices (which is needed because I will need multiple indices in the final document), so this would fail:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=references,title=References used]

\begin{document}
add something to the index \index[references]{something}
add something else to the index \index[references]{else}
add item to the index \index[references]{item}

\printindex[references]

\end{document}
```

From reading the manual and other answers here on SO, using `imakeid` and run `pdflatex` with `shell-escape` should be all. What am I missing?
I run an up to date version of miktex on windows with all packages up to date.

Comment: You shouldn't need shell escape. Use `\printindex[references]` for the named index.

Comment: Hi egreg, thanks. I've updated the example, because I did in fact use `\printindex[references]`, just didn't copy that right.
I have in fact found out that something else may cause the issues and that is that I use an output directory.

Comment: That's not supported, sorry.

Comment: well, ok then. Definitely not the answer I was hoping for. Thanks anyway

Comment: makeindex doesn't support --output-directory, so you would need some script. But I would simply not use --output-directory, imho it is more pain than gain.

Comment: Yep, guess that's it. I like the output dir since it kept my source dir clean and free of clutter. Ah well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As unfortunate as it is, output-directory is simply not supported with makeindex as you can see in the comments to my question. I could solve this with some intermediate scrips and whatnot, but let's bend instead of break and just lose the output directory, and now it all works fine.

Comment: A small patch of `imakeidx` could help you as well. See my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem and solve it using a small patch of imakeidx.

Actually, the only issue is that we have to `cd` into the build directory before calling the respective `makeindex`(or similar) program.

My patch is

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\imki@putindex
  {\imki@exec{\imki@program \imki@options #1.idx}}          %% OLD CODE
  {\imki@exec{cd build;\imki@program\imki@options#1.idx}}   %% NEW CODE: cd to build directory first
  {\message{Patch succeeded in imki@putindex}}
  {\errmessage{Patch failed in imki@putindex}}
\makeatother
```

and when I insert it immediately after the `\usepackage{imakeidx}` line of your two examples, both work out nicely for me.

Comment: Should `build` be replaced by the name of the directory? Does it works with several indexes? Can options like `program=xindy, options= -C utf8 -M my_style.xdy` be passed to `makeindex`as usual?

Comment: ```build``` is my build directory, so yes. I never worked with xindy of with several indices but I would expect it to work.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. For anyone else interested, this script requires that pdflatex is run with the flag `-shell-escape`.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of using `cd`, I was able to patch in the path like so: `{\imki@exec{\imki@program\imki@options \outputdir/#1.idx}}`, where `\edef\outputdir{\detokenize{<output-directory>}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem of makeindex not writing to a file for protection problems in books with a complex directory structure, indicated by

```
( openout_any = p)
```

in the error message is to go to `/usr/local/texlive/NNNN/tex-mf.conf` and add (using e.g. `sudo nano tex-mf.conf`)

```
openout_any = a
```

Be aware of the potentially reduced protection.